# ReactJS - You May Need an Appropriate Loader Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yA1Lw1U5278) tutorial on React (which will later take me through authentication and integration with PostgreSQL). I've noted that his react-router is outdated, and as such used the top comment to remedy that problem. However, after installing the `react-router-loader` in the `webpack.config.js` file, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./client/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/shirazchokshi/react-redux/client/index.js 
Unexpected token (7:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| render((
|   <Router>
|     <div>
|       <Route path="/" component={App} />
@ ./client/index.js 11:29-90
@ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client/index.js
```

Which doesn't make sense because I believe that I have loaded all the proper loaders in the config file. Nonetheless, below are some other files for context:

**/client/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './component/App';

render((
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </div>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

**/client/component/App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';

class App extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                Hello World!
            </div> 
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
    devtool:'eval-source-map', 
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        path.join(__dirname, '/client/index.js')
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: '/',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()

    ],  
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
                loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader', 'react-router-loader']
            }   
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [' ', '.js']
    }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "react-redux",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon --watch server --exec babel-node -- server/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-router-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-loader": "^2.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using jsx syntax in a .js file. Rename the files to have .jsx extension and use a jsx loader in your webpack configuration

Comment: wouldn't the babel-loader be able to read a jsx file? I tried renaming the file to have a .jsx extension, but I still get the same error

Comment: I suppose the problem is `include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),` you need a `/` before client. Try changing it to `include: path.join(__dirname, '/client'),`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri even after adding `/` into `include: path.join(__dirname, '/client')`, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `package.json` , I see you are using `webpack v3.4.1` . For that you need to make use of `module.rules` instead of `module.loaders` like

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, '/client'),
                use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
            }   
        ]
    },
```

See the **[documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)** and **[migration guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/)**

Comment: I think this could be the problem indeed

Comment: Didn't realize the different setup, but even after changing the config file to reflect that change, I'm still getting the same exact error.

Comment: what about this? ->  `test: /\.jsx?$/,`

Comment: Did you restart webpack?

Comment: @btzr, the OP uses .js extension only and so `test: /\.js$/,` should be fine

Comment: one more thing  make sure you have the trailing `/` before client

Comment: @FernandoPoumián Yupp, I restarted webpack

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I made sure to include everything you said, but for some reason its still returning the same error.

Comment: Can you just try removing react-router-loader from loader

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri interestingly, that worked! Could you explain why so I can understand where I went wrong?

Comment: I guess the way of using it in webpack is little bit different. See this https://github.com/luqin/react-router-loader

Answer (score 1):

In your /client/index.js, where is the "render" method coming from? Did you already import it from ReactDOM? Also, I think you might have one extra parenthesis in there:

```
render((
```

Comment: So even when I put `import {render} from 'react-dom';`, I'm getting the same error. Also, I think the second parenthesis is for containing the jsx if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Also, when I take out the other parenthesis, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The second parenthesis is not a problem, but you have to import render from react-dom

Comment: Hmm, I might be mistaken, but can you try removing the <div></div> from the Router component? So that you're only left with: 
`<Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>
`

Comment: I removed the `<div>` tag from the `render` method, and I'm still getting that error.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yep, I added that to my code, but unfortunately am still getting the same error. I will update the post to reflect that import though.

Comment: @ShirazChokshi On the same line? Which line exactly is it? Also check your bundle near your code and make sure it's been babelized.

Comment: @DaveNewton the error shifts from line 8 to line 7 when I remove the `div` tag

Comment: @ShirazChokshi And which line is that?